# Best practice updating a localized iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, localization, interface-builder

I have created an internationalized iPhone application. Now it's time to update it. What is the best practice for doing this? Do I have to edit each xib for each language or is there some way to have a "master template" that I can edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this link](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/) can help you.

That explain all ways to convert/update application.

I think the best way to you is to use `ibtool` in terminal (follow link to understand)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I am afraid that is how it works. You will have to go through each language separately. However, the nib files can be summarized with the `ibtools` utility included in the SDK. Refer to Apple's [International Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html) for clear instructions.